TestScope doesn't work in Kotlin Multiplatform
I was trying to run a unit test of my kmp code on android(local) with TestScope by injecting it into the view model.
Here's the code:
class FrankfurterRepository(engine: HttpClientEngine) {
private val BASE_URL = "https://api.frankfurter.app/latest"
private val httpClient = HttpClient(engine) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
    defaultRequest {
        url
    }
}

suspend fun getExchangeRates(exchangeRateQuery: ExchangeRateQuery): ExchangeRate {
    val response: ExchangeRate = httpClient.get(BASE_URL) {
        parameter("amount", exchangeRateQuery.amount)
        parameter("from", exchangeRateQuery.from)
        parameter("to", exchangeRateQuery.to)
    }.body()
    return response
}
}

view model:
class FrankfurterViewModel(
private val frankfurterRepository: FrankfurterRepository,
coroutineScopeProvider: CoroutineScopeProvider
 ): ViewModel() {
private val scope = coroutineScopeProvider() ?: viewModelScope
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState())
val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

fun onRate(exchangeRateQuery: ExchangeRateQuery) {
    _uiState.update { it.copy(query = exchangeRateQuery) }
    scope.launch {
        delay(100)
        getExchangeRate(exchangeRateQuery)
    }
}

 suspend fun getExchangeRate(exchangeRateQuery: ExchangeRateQuery) {
    updateResult(CustomResult.InProgress)
    try {
        val rate = frankfurterRepository.getExchangeRates(exchangeRateQuery)
        _uiState.update { it.copy(exchangeRate = rate, result = CustomResult.Success) }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        updateResult(CustomResult.Error(e.message.toString()))
    }
}
private fun updateResult(result: CustomResult) =
    _uiState.update { it.copy(result = result) }

data class UiState(
    val exchangeRate: ExchangeRate = ExchangeRate(),
    val query: ExchangeRateQuery = ExchangeRateQuery(
        amount = 1f,
        from = CurrencyEnum.USD.name,
        to = CurrencyEnum.EUR.name
    ),
    val result: CustomResult = CustomResult.Idle
)
}
class CoroutineScopeProvider(private val scope: CoroutineScope? = null) {
operator fun invoke() = scope
}

test:
open class BaseTestClass {
val testScope = TestScope()
val exception = Exception("exception")
val snackbarScope = TestScope()
val coroutineScopeProvider = CoroutineScopeProvider(testScope)
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class UnitTests: BaseTestClass() {
private lateinit var viewModel: FrankfurterViewModel

private fun mockViewModel() {
    val exchangeRate = ExchangeRate(
        amount = 1.12f,
        base = "EUR",
        date = "2023-07-17",
        rates = mapOf(CurrencyEnum.USD.name to 0.85f)
    )
    val responseContent = Json.encodeToString(ExchangeRate.serializer(), exchangeRate)
    val mockEngine = MockEngine { request ->
        respond(
            content = ByteReadChannel(responseContent),
            status = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            headers = headersOf(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "application/json")
        )
    }
    val repository = FrankfurterRepository(mockEngine)
    viewModel = FrankfurterViewModel(repository, coroutineScopeProvider)

}

@Test
fun fetchCurrency_success() = testScope.runTest {
    mockViewModel()
    viewModel.onRate(viewModel.uiState.value.query)
    advanceUntilIdle()


    println(viewModel.uiState.value.exchangeRate)
    assertEquals(CustomResult.Success, viewModel.uiState.value.result)
}

In this example, despite using advanceUntilIdle, the assertion states:
Expected :Success
Actual   :InProgress

Also, I tried testing out the delay function:
@Test
fun fetchCurrency_success() = testScope.runTest {
    delay(1000)
}

Even though the delay is equal to 1 second, the test takes just about 300ms to complete
Interestingly, if i change implementation of onRate to
fun onRate(exchangeRateQuery: ExchangeRateQuery): Job {
    _uiState.update { it.copy(query = exchangeRateQuery) }
    return scope.launch {
        delay(100)
        getExchangeRate(exchangeRateQuery)
    }
}

and join the job in test:
@Test
fun fetchCurrency_success() = testScope.runTest {
    mockViewModel()
    val job = viewModel.onRate(viewModel.uiState.value.query)
    job.join()
    
    println(viewModel.uiState.value.exchangeRate)
    assertEquals(CustomResult.Success, viewModel.uiState.value.result)
}

the assertion succeeds
